# Digital (number) length in Java

Tags: java, android, integer

How to get the length of some number in Java?

Length of string is `string.length()`, but what is it for an integer?

I tried this:

```
int lengthNumber = (String.valueOf(maxNumber)).length();
```

But it always returns 1, for every number.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: It gives me a length of 1 always, for every number.

Comment: Then maybe you're always providing a single digit number?

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates that?  That is seriously surprising.

Comment: Number is a Java Class that is why it always returns 1. If you define number instead (see answer below) it should work.

Comment: it's not call a Number, that was example. It's a **maxNumber** in my case.

Comment: Why not just use the debugger?  Put a breakpoint on this line.  maxNumber is not what you think it is but prove it with the debugger.

Comment: I resloved it. Problem was because i put code into main class of activity. When i put it into my public void method, it's working. Thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran this:

```
int Number = 100003;
int lengthNumber = (String.valueOf(Number)).length();
System.out.println(lengthNumber);
```

My output was 6, indicating that it works correctly.

Just make sure that your variables are declared properly.

This method will work if the above isn't working.

```
int x = 100003;

String y = "" + x;
```

Now you can use y.length(). Printing y gives 100003, and printing `y.length()` gives 6.

```
System.out.println(y);
System.out.println(y.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Try

```
Integer#toString().length();
```

For Example

```
Integer a=222;
int length=a.toString().length();
```

Output

```
3
```